# How to connect ElasticSearch Index(Using Logstash with MySQL to feed the data) to Java Rest High Level Client(Spring Boot)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, elasticsearch, logstash

I am able to connect to ElasticSearch Indexes when created through the Java High Level Rest Client but I want to know this:

1. Created Index(students) manually using PUT /students in POSTMAN
2. Set the Fields manually using PUT /students/_mappings in POSTMAN
3. Feeding the Data from MySQL to the Index using Logstash continuously
4. How to connect to this specific index that we created and search for documents in this index from the Spring boot application? (Note: Without using Logstash, I am able to connect to the index if I create it automatically using the Java Rest High Level Client, but if I use the Logstash and separate the Index creation, then it doesn't seem like its retrieving any records from the index).

This is my Logstash config file

```
input{
jdbc{
clean_run => true
    jdbc_driver_library => "/../mysql-connector-java-8.0.20/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exampledb?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pass"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT STUDENTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, AGE, PHONE, CITY FROM student WHERE STUDENTID > :sql_last_value;"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "studentid"
    }
    }
    output{
        elasticsearch{
            hosts=>["localhost:9200"]
            index=>"students"
            }
            stdout{
            codec => rubydebug
            }
    }
```

This is Student.class

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
@Document(indexName = "students", type = "students", shards = 1)
public class Student {

   @Id
   private long studentid;

   private String firstname;

   private String lastname;

   private int age;

   private String phone;

   private String city;
}
```

This is the StudentDAO from where I am using the ElasticSearch query.

```
 public List<Student> getAllStudents(String term, String order, String value) {

      QueryBuilder query;

      query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                           .should(
                                 QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()

                           )
                           .should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("*" + term + "*").
                                 lenient(true).field("studentid")
                                                .field("firstname")
                                                .field("lastname")
                                                .field("age")
                                                .field("phone")
                                                .field("city"));


      NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(query)
                                                                          .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0,
                                                                                1000))
                                                                          .build();

      return elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(nativeSearchQuery, Student.class);
   }
```

This is the PUT /students/_mappings

```
{
    "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "FIRSTNAME": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "LASTNAME": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "PHONE": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "AGE": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "CITY": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "STUDENTID": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you show your logstash config and your code so that we can debug the issue

Comment: Hey Opster Elasticsearch Ninja, thanks for the reply. I have added all the required details.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja Does the example help in understanding?